# opening another file from python

Tags: python

```
newquiz = input ("would you like to start a different quiz?")
if newquiz == ("yes") or start == ("yes").upper() or start == ("Yes"):
    exec ("N:\A Level work\computing coursework\quiz2.py")
```

so basically, in this code, if the user enters yes, then the code will open up my second python quiz which is in the same folder. However, when run, the code returns this:

```
syntax error: invalid syntax(<string>,line 1).
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The actual error entered by the OP is `syntax error: invalid syntax(<string>,line 1)` (I cannot fix it in the question due to a rejected proposed edit).

Comment: By the way, you are asking for trouble by using single backslash in your `exec` command - think what would happen if a directory or file name started with `n` or `r` or `t` or `b`.  Either use two backslashes or a raw string `r"N:\A Level work\computing coursework\quiz2.py"`.

Comment: @alexis I've helped you to edit the question.

Comment: @cdarke, the OP is asking for trouble in a lot of fronts :-). We all have to start somewhere. But I second the advice: I always use raw strings with Windows paths and regular expressions, it's one less thing to think about.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are using Python 2. In Python 2, `input()` will evaluate the text entered by the user as a Python expression. Change it to `raw_input(...)` and it  will work as expected.

(Better yet: Install Python 3 and use it from now on. In Python 3, `input()` does what you think it does.)

Answer (score 0):

try to use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

```
from subprocess import call

newquiz = input ("would you like to start a different quiz?")
if newquiz == ("yes") or start == ("yes").upper() or start == ("Yes"):
    call(["python", "quiz2.py"])
```